# Python Process Terminated due to "Low Swap" When Writing To stdout for Data Science

Tags: python, memory, amazon-web-services, subprocess

I'm new to python so I apologize for any misconceptions.

I have a python file that needs to read/write to stdin/stdout many many times (hundreds of thousands) for a large data science project. I know this is not ideal, but I don't have a choice in this case.

After about an hour of running (close to halfway completed), the process gets terminated on my mac due to "Low Swap" which I believe refers to lack of memory. Apart from the read/write, I'm hardly doing any computing and am really just trying to get this to run successfully before going any farther.

My Question: Does writing to stdin/stdout a few hundred thousand times use up that much memory? The file basically needs to loop through some large lists (15k ints) and do it a few thousand times. I've got 500 gigs of hard drive space and 12 gigs of ram and am still getting the errors. I even spun up an EC2 instance on AWS and STILL had memory errors. Is it possible that I have some sort of memory leak in the script even though I'm not doing hardly anything? Is there anyway that I reduce the memory usage to run this successfully?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the process gets terminated on my mac due to "Low Swap" which I believe refers to lack of memory

SWAP space is part of your Main Memory - RAM.

When a user **reads** a file it puts in it Main Memory (caches, and RAM). When its done it removes it.
However, when a user **writes** to a file, changes need to be recorded. One problem. What if you are writing to a different file every millisecond. The RAM and L caches reach capacity, so the least recently used (LRU) files are put into SWAP space. And since SWAP is still part of Main Memory (not the hard drive), it is possible to overflow it and lose information, which can cause a crash.

> Is it possible that I have some sort of memory leak in the script even though I'm not doing hardly anything?

Possibly

> Is there anyway that I reduce the memory usage to run this successfully?

One way is to think of how you are managing the file(s). Reads will not hurt SWAP because the file can just be scrapped, without the need to save. You might want to explicitly save the file (closing and opening the file should work) after a certain amount of information has been processed or a certain amount of time has gone by. Thus, removing the file from SWAP space.

Comment: Thanks for the insight - very much appreciated.